# Identify core an Erlang process

Tags: erlang

Any way to identify the specific core an Erlang process is scheduled on?

Let's say you spawn a bunch of processes to simply print out the core the process is running on, and then exit.  Any way to do this?

I spent some time reading docs and googling but couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

EDIT: "core" = CPU core number (or if not number, another identifier that identifies the CPU core).

Comment: When you say "core", what do you mean by that? CPU core number? Or Erlang node name? Did you find [`node()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#node-0)?

Comment: I mean CPU core number or other identifier.

Comment: Well, in an Erlang environment, the node name returned by `node()` is a fine identifier.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, I want to know the particular CPU core the process is scheduled on.  node() won't give me that.

Comment: The "current" CPU core is not constant and the process can shift from one CPU core to another at any time. That is just normal OS scheduling behaviour.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, that is immaterial to me and also to my question.  A process will be currently executing on a particular core.  I'd like to identify that particular core.  If the process shifts to another CPU core at another time, that is fine.  If I want, I can also print out that new core's identification.  In summary, to borrow from Bill Clinton, "it's the core, stupid."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [erlang:system_info(scheduler_id)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_scheduler_id) that in most cases is maped to a logical core. But this information is pretty ephemeral because the process may be suspended and resumed on any other scheduler.

What is your use case that you really need that kind of information?

Comment: Use case was nothing profound.  I simply wanted to see if the scheduler was indeed scheduling processes across cores, I wanted to see the distribution of the processes, and I wanted to see it happening in real-time.  Your suggestion seems to have worked, so if there isn't a better answer forthcoming I will accept yours as correct.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. If you spawn 2000 processes and they terminate quickly, chances are that you will finish the job before rebalancing occurs. In this case you would only have a single core operating all the time.

You could take a look at the scheduler utilization calls however, see `erlang:statistics(scheduler_wall_time)`. It will tell you how much work each scheduler is really doing.